# variants of ramification groups - need terminology and sources

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I've asked this question in several more elementary forums, and haven't get any answer. So I presume this is not so an elementary question.

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension, and $w$ be a valuation of a $L$, lying above a valuation $v$ of $K$. Notice that I do not suppose that $w$ is discrete.
Given a real number $\alpha >0$ in the image of $w$, each of the following can easily been shown to be a subgroup of the inertia group of $w$ in $L$ :

- $\{ \sigma\in Gal(L/K) : w(\sigma x - x) \geq \alpha \}$,
- $\{ \sigma\in Gal(L/K) : w(\sigma x - x) > \alpha \}$,
- $\{ \sigma\in Gal(L/K) : w(\sigma x - x) \geq w(x) + \alpha \}$,
- $\{ \sigma\in Gal(L/K) : w(\sigma x - x) > w(x) + \alpha \}$.

What is the terminology for these subgroups ? (I guess some variant of "ramification group of order $\alpha$") ? 
Can you indicate me sources where these groups are dealt in ?
Thx.

Comment: KConrad has weakened my initial question regarding general valuations to valuations whose group of values is the set of real numbers. I believe his reediting of the question follows from the lack of answers in the general case. Nevertheless, I would be happy to get an answer even in the general case.